# Authorizing R to access data tables in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, rstudio

I need to access the datatables in BigQuery using R but am not able to. Has anyone been able to access tables in BigQuery via RStudio?

I am successful in establising a connection using the following code but when trying to access the tables I get the error

```
bq_con <- dbConnect(bigrquery::bigquery(),
project  = "projectid",
dataset = "datasetname"
)
```

Error: Can't get Google credentials.
Are you running bigrquery in a non-interactive session? Consider:
  * Call `bq_auth()` directly with all necessary specifics.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the [Google BigQuery](https://db.rstudio.com/databases/big-query/) guide from R Studio, I tried by myself and works, here the steps I followed:

Install BigQuery package :

```
install.packages("bigrquery")
#install.packages('devtools')
devtools::install_github("rstats-db/bigrquery")
```

Install [readr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readr/index.html) package, this package provide a fast and friendly way to read 
 data:

```
install.packages("readr")
```

I ran the following code:

```
library(bigrquery)
project <- "PROJECT_ID" # put your project ID here
sql <- "SELECT * FROM [bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013] LIMIT 
1000" #use your own query
query_exec(sql, project = project)
```

After that a login page will be open, you have to type your credentials and copy & paste the authentication code and you will get the result of your query.